# Pattern matcher.group() out of bounds exception

Tags: java, regex

I have the strings:

```
    String myString1 = "22223 2342 1 98 333 3 665"

    String myString2 = "22323 3 222 34 33 1 98"
```

I want to only extract the value that has 1 digit, then a space, then only two digits.

```
    private static final Pattern p3DigitsGap = Pattern.compile(".*\\b\\d\\s\\d{2}\\b.*");
```

In both of the above strings, I'm looking to extract "1 98" I cannot just split by whitespace either side in case the pattern is at the end of the string.

```
        Matcher matcher = p3DigitsGap.matcher(myString1);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            Log.i("Matcher found");
            while (matcher.find() == true) {
                Log.i("Matcher is true");
                String extract = matcher.group(1);
                Log.d("extract: " + extract);
            }
        }
```

The String extract is never populated and throws an out of bounds exception if I remove the while loop. I added in the while loop and matcher.find() doesn't equal true.

I tried swapping my pattern to:

```
    Pattern p3DigitsGap = Pattern.compile("[^0-9a-z]\\d\\s\\d{2}[^0-9a-z]");
```

I thought that the use of the .*\\b may be causing the issue, but I get the same result.

Please can someone help me understand where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

ANSWER EDIT: I marked the answer by Reimeus correct, as it works by using groups with the above regex. Please also see the answer by Tim Pietzcker for an alternative solution that improves on my original regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use [groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) when matching, so you could use:

```
Pattern p3DigitsGap = Pattern.compile(".*\\b(\\d\\s\\d{2})\\b.*");
Matcher matcher = p3DigitsGap.matcher(myString1);
if (matcher.find()) {
   Log.i("Matcher is true");
   String extract = matcher.group(1);
   Log.d("extract: " + extract);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I adjust your answer slightly so that the brackets surround (\\d\\s\\d{2}) I get the correct output of "1 98". Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, my bad, forgot about the the space & 2 digits, have updated with correct answer

Comment: @andjav will be failed when your input is `"1 98 333 3 665"` or `"22223 2342 1 98"`, see my answer!

Comment: @turtledove I treble checked with some random strings and it doesn't fail when at the beginning or the end? \\b is the boundary. Appreciate your efforts though, but this answer works with the original regex.

Comment: @andjav yes, you are right, i was wrong! `"\\b\\d\\s\\d{2}\\b"` is ok!

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- You don't have any capturing groups in your regex, so the highest valid group of any match will be `.group(0)` (the entire match).
- Your example strings match exactly once, but you call `matcher.find()` twice, so the second call (in the `while` loop) returns no match.

Try this:

```
Pattern p3DigitsGap = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d\\s\\d{2}\\b");
Matcher matcher = p3DigitsGap.matcher(myString1);
if (matcher.find()) {
    Log.i("Matcher found");
    String extract = matcher.group(0);
    Log.d("extract: " + extract);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but matcher.group(0) returns the entire contents of myString1 ?

Comment: @andjav: right, you need to remove both `.*`s from your first regex.

Comment: Why do you suggest that? It works fine both at the beginning and end of potential String matches.

Comment: @andjav: Because it's much more efficient. `.*` first matches the *entire* string, then has to backtrack until your "proper" regex matches, then `.*` matches the rest of string *again*, and *then* you throw all that away. Reimeus' solution works fine, but with my solution, you don't need a capturing group, *and* it's much faster. But it's your decision.

Comment: I've tested what you've said, but I don't get a match at all if I use the regex ("\\b\\d\\s\\d{2}\\b") It only gets a match if I put .* either side?

Comment: I doubt that, unless you're using `matcher.matches()` instead of `matcher.find()`.

Comment: Yes! I am, for the original surrounding IF. I don't understand why .matches() would return false, but I shall go and do some reading! The surrounding IF is most probably unnecessary - Thank you for your comments. I've already marked another answer as correct, as it 'worked'- apologies, I shall reference your answer in my question for the correct and faster regex.

Comment: @andjav: `.matches()` forces the *entire* string to match. This trips up users all the time. The surrounding `if` is indeed unnecessary (and may be even harmful, as I've pointed out in this answer).

Comment: Removed the IF and changed the regex as you suggested - works and is of course much better. Thank you for returning to explain, it makes sense now. I've referenced your answer in the question.

Answer (score 1):

you have no group defined, you can defined a group using `( and )`, and i think your code should be:

```
 private static final Pattern p3DigitsGap = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d\\s\\d{2}\\b");
 Matcher matcher = p3DigitsGap.matcher(myString1);
 while (matcher.find()) {
   Log.i("Matcher is true");
   String extract = matcher.group(0);
   Log.d("extract: " + extract);
 }
```

Comment: matcher.group(0) returns the entire contents of myString1 ?

Comment: @andjav no, group(0) return the whole matched string. i just found your regexp is wrong, i changed my answer, have a try!

Comment: Doesn't (?=<\\s) denote whitespace? I think Reimeus might have the solution above with ( brackets ) surrounding the area I want to extract to group(1). Perhaps that's what you meant by ( and ). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @andjav no `?=<` means lookbehind and not consume, `?=` means lookahead and not consume. I updated my answer again, because it fails when your input is `"1 98 333 3 665"` or `"22223 2342 1 98"`

Comment: Lookbehind is `(?<=…)`, not `(?=<…)`.  But never mind: lookaround is not the best tool for this job anyway.